# Region about shapes such as what is the region of the shape

Tags: geometry

What is the meaning of region when it says,
'what is the biggest number of region that can be formed on the surface.'

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: This is much too vague to make sense.